# Are there any AWK syntax checkers?

Tags: awk, syntax-checking

Are there any AWK syntax checkers? I'm interested in both minimal checkers that only flag syntax errors and more extensive checkers along the lines of lint.

It should be a static checker only, not dependent on running the script.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you prefix your Awk script with `BEGIN { exit(0) } END { exit(0) }`, you're guaranteed that none of your of code will run. Exiting during `BEGIN` and `END` prevents other begin and exit blocks from running. If Awk returns 0, your script was fine; otherwise there was a syntax error.

If you put the code snippet in a separate argument, you'll get good line numbers in the error messages. This invocation...

```
gawk --source 'BEGIN { exit(0) } END { exit(0) }' --file syntax-test.awk
```

Gives error messages like this:

```
gawk: syntax-test.awk:3:   x = f(
gawk: syntax-test.awk:3:         ^ unexpected newline or end of string
```

GNU Awk's `--lint` can spot things like global variables and undefined functions:

```
gawk: syntax-test.awk:5: warning: function `g': parameter `x' shadows global variable
gawk: warning: function `f' called but never defined
```

And GNU Awk's `--posix` option can spot some compatibility problems:

```
gawk: syntax-test.awk:2: error: `delete array' is a gawk extension
```

### Update: `BEGIN` and `END`

Although the `END { exit(0) }` block seems redundant, compare the subtle differences between these three invocations:

```
$ echo | awk '
  BEGIN { print("at begin") }
  /.*/ { print("found match") }
  END { print("at end") }'
at begin
found match
at end

$ echo | awk '
  BEGIN { exit(0) }
  BEGIN { print("at begin") }
  /.*/ { print("found match") }
  END { print("at end") }'
at end

$ echo | awk '
  BEGIN { exit(0) } END { exit(0) }
  BEGIN { print("at begin") }
  /.*/ { print("found match") }
  END { print("at end") }'
```

In Awk, exiting during `BEGIN` will cancel all other begin blocks, and will prevent matching against any input. Exiting during `END` is the only way to prevent all other event blocks from running; that's why the third invocation above shows that no print statements were executed. The GNU Awk User's Guide has a section on the [`exit` statement](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html#Exit-Statement).

Comment: The `END { exit(0) }` doesn't really seem necessary. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Michael J. Barber: I've added an update to my answer to show the difference that it makes.

Comment: @Michael J. Barber: :) No problem.

Answer (score 2):

GNU awk appears to have a [`--lint` option](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#index-_002d_002dlint-option).

Comment: The documentation for which suggests it focuses on differences between awk and gawk. Is it actually a syntax checker or a compatibility check? Either way it doesn't quite fit my needs, as it does some checks at runtime; I've edited the question to specify that.

Comment: Oh, and +1 for the suggestion, it's certainly better than the nothing I have.

Answer (score 0):

For a minimal syntax checker, which stops at the first error, try `awk -f prog < /dev/null`.

Comment: but that may execute some code within the awk script despite getting no file input. For example BEGIN { system("rm importantFile") }

Comment: Indeed, that looks definitely unsafe.